# How can I select the first word of every line of a block of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to select each first word, to wrap it in a specific span.

> **Lorem** ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras
>   sagittis nunc non nisi venenatis
>   auctor. **Aliquam** consectetur pretium
>   sapien, eget congue purus egestas nec.
>   Maecenas sed purus ut turpis **varius**
>   dictum. Praesent a nunc ipsum, id
>   mattis odio. Donec rhoncus posuere
>   bibendum. Fusce **nulla** elit, laoreet
>   non posuere.

If this is the text, the script should select Lorem, Aliquam, varius and nulla.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have each line in a separate <p> tag or have each line ending with a <br /> ?

Comment: Improve your question with some more description

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *can* do this, by using JavaScript to wrap every word in the paragraph in its own span, and then walking through the spans finding out what their actual position on the page is, and then applying your style changes to the spans whose Y position is greater than the preceding span. (Best do it beginning-to-end, though, as earlier ones may well affect the wrapping of latter ones.) But it's going to be a *lot of work* for the browser, and you'll have to repeat it each time the window is resized, so the effect will have to be worth the cost.

Something like this (used jQuery as you've listed the `jquery` tag on your question):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var lasty;
  
  var $target = $('#target');
  $target.html(
    "<span>" +
    $target.text().split(/\s/).join("</span> <span>") +
    "</span>");
  lasty = -1;
  $target.find('span').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        top = $this.position().top;
    if (top > lasty) {
      $this.css("fontWeight", "bold");
      lasty = top;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id='target' style='width: 20em'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sagittis nunc non nisi venenatis auctor. Aliquam consectetur pretium sapien, eget congue purus egestas nec. Maecenas sed purus ut turpis varius dictum. Praesent a nunc ipsum, id mattis odio. Donec rhoncus posuere bibendum. Fusce nulla elit, laoreet non posuere.</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Naturally that's making a huge set of assumptions (that all whitespace should be replaced with a single space, that there's no markup in the text, probably others). But you get the idea.

Here's a version that handles window resize, 50ms after the last resize event occurs (so we're not doing it interim) and with Gaby's suggestion (below) that we unbold at the start of the resize:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var resizeTriggerHandle = 0;

  // Do it on load
  boldFirstWord('#target');
  
  // Do it 100ms after the end of a resize operation,
  // because it's *expensive*
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (resizeTriggerHandle != 0) {
      clearTimeout(resizeTriggerHandle);
    }
    unboldFirstWord('#target');
    resizeTriggerHandle = setTimeout(function() {
      resizeTriggerHandle = 0;
      boldFirstWord('#target');
    }, 50);
  });
  
  function boldFirstWord(selector) {
    var lasty;

    // Break into spans if not already done;
    // if already done, remove any previous bold
    var $target = $(selector);
    if (!$target.data('spanned')) {
      $target.html(
        "<span>" +
        $target.text().split(/\s/).join("</span> <span>") +
        "</span>");
      $target.data('spanned', true);
    }
    else {
      unboldFirstWord($target);
    }

    // Apply bold to first span of each new line
    lasty = -1;
    $target.find('span').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          top = $this.position().top;
      if (top > lasty) {
        $this.css("fontWeight", "bold");
        lasty = top;
      }
    });
    $target.data('bolded', true);
  }
  
  function unboldFirstWord(selector) {
    var $target = selector.jquery ? selector : $(selector);
    if ($target.data('spanned') && $target.data('bolded')) {
      $target.find('span').css("fontWeight", "normal");
      $target.data('bolded', false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='target'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sagittis nunc non nisi venenatis auctor. Aliquam consectetur pretium sapien, eget congue purus egestas nec. Maecenas sed purus ut turpis varius dictum. Praesent a nunc ipsum, id mattis odio. Donec rhoncus posuere bibendum. Fusce nulla elit, laoreet non posuere. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sagittis nunc non nisi venenatis auctor. Aliquam consectetur pretium sapien, eget congue purus egestas nec. Maecenas sed purus ut turpis varius dictum. Praesent a nunc ipsum, id mattis odio. Donec rhoncus posuere bibendum. Fusce nulla elit, laoreet non posuere. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sagittis nunc non nisi venenatis auctor. Aliquam consectetur pretium sapien, eget congue purus egestas nec. Maecenas sed purus ut turpis varius dictum. Praesent a nunc ipsum, id mattis odio. Donec rhoncus posuere bibendum. Fusce nulla elit, laoreet non posuere. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sagittis nunc non nisi venenatis auctor. Aliquam consectetur pretium sapien, eget congue purus egestas nec. Maecenas sed purus ut turpis varius dictum. Praesent a nunc ipsum, id mattis odio. Donec rhoncus posuere bibendum. Fusce nulla elit, laoreet non posuere. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sagittis nunc non nisi venenatis auctor. Aliquam consectetur pretium sapien, eget congue purus egestas nec. Maecenas sed purus ut turpis varius dictum. Praesent a nunc ipsum, id mattis odio. Donec rhoncus posuere bibendum. Fusce nulla elit, laoreet non posuere.</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar for the last word of each line? (Or should I start a new topic for this question?)

Comment: @Teis: Sure, just save a reference to the last word in the loop (like `lasty`, and if you see that the next word starts a new line, apply the CSS or whatever to the last one instead of the current one.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('p').each(function() {
    var text_splited = $(this).text().split(" ");
    $(this).html("<strong>"+text_splited.shift()+"</strong> "+text_splited.join(" "));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sagittis nunc non nisi venenatis auctor.</p>
<p>Aliquam consectetur pretium sapien, eget congue purus egestas nec. Maecenas sed purus ut turpis varius dictum.</p>
<p>Praesent a nunc ipsum, id mattis odio. Donec rhoncus posuere bibendum. Fusce nulla elit, laoreet non posuere.</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work -- when the text is longer than the page and wraps, the first word of the second line isn't also highlighted, as OP requests.

Answer (score 0):

To bold every first word of a `<p>` tag, including whitespace after the initial `<p>`, use some regular expressions:

```js
$('p').each(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    me.html( me.text().replace(/(^\w+|\s+\w+)/,'&lt;strong&gt;$1&lt;/strong&gt;') );
});
```

Comment: This will clear out any extra elements inside those `p` elements.